# Composer update exceptions eg requires omnipay/common

Tags: composer-php, omnipay

I have just run

```
$ composer self-update
```

on Windows 7, but when I run

```
$ composer update
```

to update dependencies I get the following messages:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

  [Composer\DependencyResolver\SolverProblemsException]
    Problem 1
      - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.4.* -> satisfiable by la
  ravel/framework[5.4.x-dev].
      - laravel/framework 5.4.x-dev requires doctrine/inflector ~1.1.0 -> no
  matching package found.
    Problem 2
      - Installation request for omnipay/omnipay 2.* -> satisfiable by omnipa
  y/omnipay[2.3.x-dev].
      - omnipay/omnipay 2.3.x-dev requires omnipay/common ~2.3 -> no matching
   package found.
    Problem 3
      - Installation request for omnipay/stripe ~2.0 -> satisfiable by omnipa
  y/stripe[V2.4.7].
      - omnipay/stripe V2.4.7 requires omnipay/common ~2.0 -> no matching pac
  kage found.
    Problem 4
      - Installation request for omnipay/paypal ~2.0 -> satisfiable by omnipa
  y/paypal[v2.6.3].
      - omnipay/paypal v2.6.3 requires omnipay/common ~2.0 -> no matching pac
  kage found.
    Problem 5
      - Installation request for omnipay/mollie 3.* -> satisfiable by omnipay
  /mollie[3.2.x-dev].
      - omnipay/mollie 3.2.x-dev requires omnipay/common ~2.2 -> no matching
  package found.
    Problem 6
      - laravel/framework 5.4.x-dev requires doctrine/inflector ~1.1.0 -> no
  matching package found.
      - laravelcollective/html 5.4.x-dev requires illuminate/http 5.4.* -> sa
  tisfiable by laravel/framework[5.4.x-dev].
      - Installation request for laravelcollective/html * -> satisfiable by l
  aravelcollective/html[5.4.x-dev].
  Potential causes:
   - A typo in the package name
   - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to you
  r minimum-stability setting
     see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for mor
  e details.
  Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further
  common problems.
```

In particular I want to update `omnipay/stripe`. My `composer.json` includes the following in its `require` section for omnipay:

```
"omnipay/omnipay": "2.*",
"omnipay/stripe": "~2.0",
"omnipay/common": "*",
```

Also, the minimum stability is set to `dev`:

```
"minimum-stability": "dev"
```

To try and solve the first error that refers to Laravel, I've tried adding `"doctrine/inflector": "*"` to the `require` section of `composer.json` and also deleted the `composer.lock` file, but an error says the package can't be found. [This post](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/20328) seems to suggest that doctrine requires PHP 7 with Laravel 5.4 so maybe that's the issue as I'm running PHP 5.6

Seems it is an issue relating to Laravel because if I remove `"laravel/framework": "5.4.*"` from `composer.json` then the other updates work ok without error.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem from the fragments of `composer.json` you posted. `laravel/framework:5.4.*` requires `doctrine/inflector:~1.1.0`, and this requires PHP 5.6 only. One suggestion, though, if you decide to set the `minimum-stability` to `dev`, you probably want to prefer stable versions at the same time, see https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#prefer-stable.

Comment: You do not need to include omnipay/omnipay or omnipay/common in your composer.json.  Just include the relevant versions of omnipay/stripe and the necessary dependencies will be pulled in automatically.  Including a specific version identifier for omnipay/common can cause the error you're seeing.